# My CSS won't link to my HTML file

Tags: html, css, hyperlink

I am trying to build a simple website in Sublime Text Editor 2, however, my CSS file won't link to my HTML file and therefore printing plain text. My HTML code is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/       xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title>Christopher Olson</title>
<link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300,600,700" rel="stylesheet" />

<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" />
```

As far as I know, the last line is supposed to link the CSS file.

This is part of the CSS that I have:

```
body, input, textarea
{
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    line-height: 1.85em;
    color: #888;
    font-weight: 300;
}
```

Any ideas to fix? Please help

EDIT: I have the  tags, I just ran out of room to post it

Comment: can you show us your projects directory structure?

Comment: The URL provided is not correct, probably.

Comment: HTML links to CSS not the other way around. Just as a heads up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Definitely is your link's href incorrect.

Answer (score 8):

Your path your CSS file is probably wrong. If you're sane your CSS directory is in the webroot so your `<link>` should probably look like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/style.css" />
```

Comment: Just Ctrl-U and see source of your own html through browser and click on css link if it dont show ur css then path is missing

Comment: In addition to this answer: use a tool like Firebug for Firefox. Use the "net" tab on Firebug to see if all your resources are being loaded. I'd use root relative paths as demonstraded in this answer, then you don't have to worry too much about the folder/file structure.

Answer (score 2):

The link to your css files will be relative to the location of your html file. If both are int the same directory, then just include the name of the css file, if it is in a folder named "css" and that folder is in the same directory as your html file then you do "css/"

Answer (score 0):

I think your href is wrong

You can tried using a absolute url just like

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://..../css/style.css" />
```

You can download a very nice plugin for firefox called "firebug" it show you when some resource can't be reach

Comment: that is not any kind of valid URL.

Answer (score -2):

It will 100% work if your "call" link is placed within the html file. I'm having the same issue, my only work around is to include the call links in both the .html and .css ball ache, but it works

Comment: This could be a simple comment.